# redirect page if address extension id= 'x'?

Tags: php, redirect

I'm trying to find a way of redirecting a page in php if a user clicks a link that will basically take them from a page called 'profile.php?id=99994' (if id extension is equal to '99994') and redirect them to page.php.

Can this be done?

I know it's a really odd question but it's got to be done this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($_GET['id'] == 99994) {
    header("Location: /pathto/page.php");
    exit;
}
```

The php function `header()` is used to redirect pages. Obviously I don't know your path system, so you'll have to tweak that a little bit. But this code will redirect when the `$_GET` value of "ID" is equal (and ONLY equal) to 99994.

Comment: `isset` is going to return `true` or `false`, not `99994`.

Comment: You should still keep the `isset`, though, because it might show a notice for other pages :)

Comment: You should indeed keep the isset in there. Because what if no id was given through $_GET? You'll get a undefined error. Or you could add a @ to suppress the error, like so: @$_GET['id']

Answer (score 2):

As in, from inside `profile.php`?

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] === '99994') {
    header('Location: page.php');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: yea that's the thing i'm looking for. i'll try it.